# Cannot access a closed stream error while using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, stream, itext

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
>          at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
>          at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.WriteTo(Stream os)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Write(PdfIndirectObject indirect, Int32 refNumber, Int32 generation)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, Int32 refNumber, Int32 generation, Boolean inObjStm)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddToBody(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.Type1Font.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer, PdfIndirectReference piref, Object[] parms)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.FontDetails.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddSharedObjectsToBody()
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
>          at iTextSharp.text.DocWriter.Dispose()

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAjax]
public ActionResult CreatePdf(string htmlData)
{
    string fileName = "BillInvoice.pdf";
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25))
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    using (var srHtml = new StringReader(htmlData))
                    {
                        iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                    }
                    CurrentHomeView = GetHomeView();
                    List<string> signBase64List = new List<string>()
                    {
                        CurrentHomeView.BillSig.GmSignature,
                        CurrentHomeView.BillSig.DMSignature
                    };
                    foreach (var sign in signBase64List)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sign))
                        {
                            string certbase64 = sign.Substring(sign.IndexOf(',') + 1);
                            doc.Add(ConvertImage(certbase64));
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            TempData[fileName] = ms;
            //ms.Position = 0;
        }
        return Json(new { success = true, fileName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        fileName = e.ToString();
        return Json(new { success = false, fileName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public iTextSharp.text.Image ConvertImage(string base64String)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image png = null;

    Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);

    return png;
}

public ActionResult DownloadCertPdf(string fileName)
{
    var ms = TempData[fileName] as MemoryStream;
    if (ms == null)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
    TempData[fileName] = null;
    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf", fileName);
}
```

I have checked other similar question on the same topic but non of them are resolved.

I am using ItextSharp to generate pdf from Html tag.

on document load, one of my function loop through and created Table tags for each section which is then passed via ajax to my MVC Controller.

For test purpose when I hard code wrote the table tags and passed it did not throw any exception But when I created the table tags by looping through dom , I got below exception.

My code is :

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? I'm going to guess it's in the DownloadCertPDF action? Your memoryStream was closed. You're now outside the `using` statement which opened it - in fact you're not even in the same request any more. I don't understand why you don't just generate the PDF and download it all in one action method? Why do you need an ajax call first?

Comment: According to the stack trace the exception occurs at the end of the `using (writer)` block. Actually there is no need for putting a `using` here anyways as closing the `doc` implicitly will close the `writer`. And there is no need for explicitly closing the `doc` as it implicitly is closed by the `using (doc)`. Thus, I would remove these unnecessary things and check again.

Comment: i am doing ajax call because, the application already has print html page. so if i create another action, i am going to write same code which print html already have. so what i am trying here is grabbing all data which is already in print html and creating pdf out of it.

Comment: when i did not put using statement on wrtier , this line threw different exception  iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);